# Closing a Java FileInputStream

Tags: java, exception, stream

Alright, I have been doing the following (variable names have been changed):

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
try
{
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    ... process ...

}
catch (IOException e)
{
    ... handle error ...
}
finally
{
    if (fis != null)
        fis.close();
}
```

Recently, I started using FindBugs, which suggests that I am not properly closing streams.  I decide to see if there's anything that can be done with a finally{} block, and then I see, oh yeah, close() can throw IOException.  What are people supposed to do here?  The Java libraries throw too many checked exceptions.

Comment: `fis` cannot possibly be null at the point you are testing it. It can be null in the missing `finally` block where you should be testing it and closing it. But the question is obsolete since the introduction of the 'try-with-resources' syntax.

Comment: I've modified the code accordingly just so people aren't mislead.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For Java 7 and above [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) should be used:

```
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
  // TODO: work
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO: handle error
}
```

If you're stuck on Java 6 or below...

This pattern avoids mucking around with **null**:

```
    try {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            // TODO: work
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: error handling
    }
```

---

For a more detail on how to effectively deal with *close*, read this blog post: [Java: how not to make a mess of stream handling](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/10/java-how-not-to-make-mess-of-stream.html). It has more sample code, more depth and covers the pitfalls of wrapping *close* in a *catch* block.

Answer (score 26):

Something like the following should do it, up to you whether you throw or swallow the IOException on attempting to close the stream.

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
try
{
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    ... process ...


}
catch (IOException e)
{
    ... blah blah blah ...
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        if (fis != null)
            fis.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use the [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html) feature added JDK7. It was created precisely to deal with this kind of things

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
  try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    return br.readLine();
  }
}
```

The documenation says:

> The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed
>   at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a simple static Helper Method:

```
public static void closeQuietly(InputStream s) {
   if (null == s) {
      return;
   }
   try {
      s.close();
   } catch (IOException ioe) {
      //ignore exception
   }
}
```

and use this from your finally block.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing much to add, except for a very minor stylistic suggestion.  **The canonical example of self documenting code** applies in this case - give a descriptive variable name to the ignored `IOException` that you must catch on `close()`.

So squiddle's answer becomes:

```
public static void closeQuietly(InputStream s) {
   try {
      s.close();
   } catch (IOException ignored) {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, I find it is just better **not** to catch the IO exceptions, and simply use try-finally:

```
final InputStream is = ... // (assuming some construction that can't return null)
try {
    // process is
    ...
} finally {
    is.close();
}
```

Except for `FileNotFoundException`, you generally can't "work around" an `IOException`. The only thing left to do is report an error, and you will typically handle that further up the call stack, so I find it better to propagate the exception.

Since `IOException` is a checked exception, you will have to declare that this code (and any of its clients) `throws IOException`. That might be too noisy, or you might not want to reveal the implementation detail of using IO. In that case, you can wrap the entire block with an exception handler that wraps the `IOException` in a `RuntimeException` or an abstract exception type.

**Detail:** I am aware that the above code swallows any exception from the `try` block when the `close` operation in the `finally` block produces an `IOException`. I don't think that is a big problem: generally, the exception from the `try` block will be the same `IOException` that causes the `close` to fail (i.e. it is quite rare for IO to work fine and then fail at the point of closing). If this is a concern, it might be worth the trouble to "silence" the close.

Comment: It's quite rare to the point of being unknown in the case of an input stream. An output stream can fail on `close()` due to the implied `flush()` that happens on any stream derived from `FilterInputStream.`

Answer (score 1):

The following solution correctly throws an exception if close fails without hiding a possible exception before the close.

```
try {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    try {
        // work
        in.close();
    } finally {
        Closeables.closeQuietly(in);
    }
} catch(IOException exc) {
    // kernel panic
}
```

This works because calling close a second time [has no effect](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html#close()).

This relies on guava [Closeables](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Closeables.html), but one can write its own closeQuietly method if preferred, as shown by [squiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156508/closing-a-java-fileinputstream/156526#156526) (see also [serg10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156508/closing-a-java-fileinputstream/156674#156674)).

Reporting a close error, in the general case, is important because close might write some final bytes to the stream, e.g. because of buffering. Hence, your user wants to know if it failed, or you probably want to act somehow. Granted, this might not be true in the specific case of a FileInputStream, I don't know (but for reasons already mentioned I think it is better to report a close error if it occurs anyway).

The above code is a bit difficult to grasp because of the structure of the embedded try blocks. It might be considered clearer with two methods, one that throws an IOException and one that catches it. At least that is what I would opt for.

```
private void work() throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    try {
        // work
        in.close();
    } finally {
        Closeables.closeQuietly(in);
    }
}

public void workAndDealWithException() {
    try {
        work();
    } catch(IOException exc) {
        // kernel panic
    }
}
```

Based on http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/10/java-how-not-to-make-mess-of-stream.html (referenced by McDowell).

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully we will get closures in Java some day, and then we will lose lots of the verbosity.

So instead there will be a helper method somwhere in javaIO that you can import, it will probably takes a "Closable" interface and also a block. Inside that helper method the try {closable.close() } catch (IOException ex){ //blah} is defined once and for all, and then you will be able to write

```
 Inputstream s = ....;
 withClosable(s) {
    //your code here
 }
```

Answer (score -4):

Are you concerned primarily with getting a clean report from FindBugs or with having code that works? These are not necessarily the same thing. Your original code is fine (although I would get rid of the redundant `if (fis != null)` check since an `OutOfMemoryException` would have been thrown otherwise). FileInputStream has a finalizer method which will close the stream for you in the unlikely event that you actually receive an IOException in your processing. It's simply not worth the bother of making your code more sophisticated to avoid the extremely unlikely scenario of

1. you get an IOException and
2. this happens so often that you start to run into finalizer backlog issues.

**Edit:** if you are getting so many IOExceptions that you are running into problems with the finalizer queue then you have far far bigger fish to fry! This is about getting a sense of perspective.

Comment: Relying on finalizers here is a very bad move. The finalizer will only be called when the stream object is garbage collected, and you're likely to tun out of file handles long before that happens.

*Never* rely on finalizers for functionality. I can't stress that enough.

Comment: There is no guarantee of whether a finalizer will be run at all.

Comment: I know about the dangers of relying on finalizers. My point was simply that getting IOExceptions is not a normal flow and for this unusual case it's probably not worth getting too hung up on closing the file descriptor there and then. When did you last see multiple IOExceptions on a FileInputStream and did you consider this normal behaviour that a program should deal with and continue running?